# Texmaker Hangs on Process started

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texmaker, breqn

When I try to run my script in Texmaker, Texmaker gives me the message "Process started" but hangs on it forever and never actually finishes compiling. I know these are long equations, but Texmaker should be able to handle an entire dissertation. Also, I need to use breqn, because I need to break the equations across lines despite the fact there are groups (I need \left( and \right) on different lines sometimes). I am also using Texmaker PDFLaTeX, if that is relevant. Anyway, I am new to Texmaker and LaTeX, and any help would be very much appreciated! This is what I try to run:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times, amsmath, setspace, breqn}

\doublespace

\begin{document}

\noindent

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{dmath}[style={\mathindent=0pt}]
\left((-1-n) \left(-1/((-2+n) \sigma_{i} )k^2 x_{\alpha,i,j}  \left|\frac{y_{i} -\mu_{i} }{\sigma_{i} }\right|^{-1+k} \left(\left(\frac{k}{-2+n}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}} \\
\times \sqrt{B\left[\frac{1}{k},\frac{n}{k}\right]}\right)^{-k} \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{12 tan^{-1}[\phi_{i} ]^2}{\pi ^2}-\frac{16 tan^{-1}[\phi_{i} ]^2 B\left[\frac{2}{k},\frac{-1+n}{k}\right]^2}{\pi ^2 B\left[\frac{1}{k},\frac{n}{k}\right] B\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{-2+n}{k}\right]}} \\
\times \sqrt{B\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{-2+n}{k}\right]}\right)^k \left(1+\frac{2 tan^{-1}[\phi_{i} ] sgn[y_{i} -\mu_{i} ]}{\pi}\right)^{-k} \sgn\left[\frac{y_{i} -\mu_{i} }{\sigma_{i} }\right] \\
+1/((-2+n) \pi )2 k^2 x_{\alpha,i,j}  \left|\frac{y_{i} -\mu_{i} }{\sigma_{i} }\right|^k tan^{-1}[\phi_{i} ] \left(\left(\frac{k}{-2+n}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}} \sqrt{B\left[\frac{1}{k},\frac{n}{k}\right]}\right)^{-k} \\
\times \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{12 tan^{-1}[\phi_{i} ]^2}{\pi ^2}-\frac{16 tan^{-1}[\phi_{i} ]^2 B\left[\frac{2}{k},\frac{-1+n}{k}\right]^2}{\pi^2 B\left[\frac{1}{k},\frac{n}{k}\right] B\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{-2+n}{k}\right]}} \sqrt{B\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{-2+n}{k}\right]}\right)^k \\
/\left(k\left(1+1/(-2+n)k \left|\frac{y_{i} -\mu_{i} }{\sigma_{i} }\right|^k \left(\left(\frac{k}{-2+n}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}} \sqrt{B\left[\frac{1}{k},\frac{n}{k}\right]}\right)^{-k} \\
\times \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{12 tan^{-1}[\phi_{i} ]^2}{\pi ^2}-\frac{16 tan^{-1}[\phi_{i} ]^2 B\left[\frac{2}{k},\frac{-1+n}{k}\right]^2}{\pi^2 B\left[\frac{1}{k},\frac{n}{k}\right] B\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{-2+n}{k}\right]}}    \sqrt{B\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{-2+n}{k}\right]}\right)^k \\
\times \left(1+\frac{2 tan^{-1}[\phi_{i} ] sgn[y_{i} -\mu_{i} ]}{\pi }\right)^{-k}\right)\right)
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Note that breqn allows you to break across lines. For instance, this runs fine:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times, amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace, breqn}

\doublespace

\begin{document}

\noindent

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{dmath}[style={\mathindent=0pt}]
-\text{Log}[2]+\text{Log}[k]-\text{Log}[\beta  \psi ]-\frac{3}{2}\text{Log}\left[\text{Beta}\left[\frac{1}{k},\frac{n}{k}\right]\right]+\frac{1}{2} \text{Log}\left[1+\frac{12 \text{ArcTan}[\gamma  \omega ]^2}{\pi ^2}-\frac{16 \text{ArcTan}[\gamma  \omega ]^2 \text{Beta}\left[\frac{2}{k},\frac{-1+n}{k}\right]^2}{\pi^2 \text{Beta}\left[\frac{1}{k},\frac{n}{k}\right] \text{Beta}\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{-2+n}{k}\right]}\right]+\frac{1}{2} \text{Log}\left[\text{Beta}\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{-2+n}{k}\right]\right]+\frac{1}{k}(-1-n) \text{Log}\left[1+1/(-2+n)k \text{Abs}\left[\frac{x-\alpha  \chi }{\beta  \psi }\right]^k \left(\left(\frac{k}{-2+n}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}} \sqrt{\text{Beta}\left[\frac{1}{k},\frac{n}{k}\right]}\right)^{-k} \\ 
\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{12 \text{ArcTan}[\gamma  \omega ]^2}{\pi ^2}-\frac{16 \text{ArcTan}[\gamma  \omega ]^2 \text{Beta}\left[\frac{2}{k},\frac{-1+n}{k}\right]^2}{\pi^2 \text{Beta}\left[\frac{1}{k},\frac{n}{k}\right] \text{Beta}\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{-2+n}{k}\right]}} \sqrt{\text{Beta}\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{-2+n}{k}\right]}\right)^k \\
\left(1+\frac{2 \text{ArcTan}[\gamma  \omega ] \text{Sign}[x-\alpha  \chi ]}{\pi }\right)^{-k}\right]
\end{dmath}
Alpha
\end{document}
```

and the output is:

[image: and this looks just like I need it to]

Comment: You are performing a manual break in the equation using `\\`, yet you haven't supplied the appropriate `\right`-pair for every `\left` one.

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! The `\doublespace` command is not defined, meaning you are missing a package which defines that. You must add `\usepackage{setspace}` in the preamble of the document. Yes, as it is mentioned by Werner, the key problem is pairing of symbols. TeX raises an error and therefore TeXmaker crashes (`pdflatex` is running in the background, so `pdflatex` is crashing to be exact).

Comment: It is PDFLaTex, sorry. So it is my impression that breqn allows you to break even within a group. For example, this runs fine:

Comment: @Malipivo: pdflatex is not _crashing_, it merely exits after reporting an error (on stdout and in the log file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to compile your source from terminal with "pdflatex" command.
the command should not hang, then, you can see the error(s).
I had a similar problem with TexMaker.Hopefully, that's not frequent.