# No error message in texmaker

Tags: errors, texmaker

when compiling, if I make any syntax mistake the message box simply says "Process started" without giving any specific error message or saying which line the error is in so I need to manually search for the error.

I did not have this problem before, I don't know what changed.

Comment: Related? [Texmaker Hangs on Process started](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169282/5764); [TeXmaker is stuck on "Process Started"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317159/5764)

Comment: unfortunately not, it hangs on process started for any silly mistake, as forgetting a $.

Comment: Look at some proposed solutions/discussion from [a Google search](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=texmaker+process+started).

Comment: When I make no errors the output is produced. It is just a problem concerning the production of message error, not nature of error